# Object is not disposed along all execution paths

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have the following code.

```
private DataTable LoadSMSCellProviders()
{
    string sqlQuery = "Select * from SMSAddress";
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Utility.ConnString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
    }
}
```

The Microsoft Code Analysis is telling me that `dt` is not disposed along all execution paths, but I am not sure how to correct this. If I try to call `dispose` on it before the `return`, it will return a null value, and if I try to do it at the end of the method, the code is never reached...

What am I missing here?

This is the message from the analysis tool:

> warning : CA2000 : Microsoft.Reliability : In method 'x.x()', object
>   'dt' is not disposed along all exception paths. Call
>   System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'dt' before all references to it
>   are out of scope.

Comment: The idea is that you need to dispose of it if an exception occurs.

Comment: It is the responsibility of the calling method to `LoadSMSCellProviders()` to dispose of the returned `DataTable`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to dispose of it when an exception occurs.  Like this.

```
private DataTable LoadSMSCellProviders()
{
    string sqlQuery = "Select * from SMSAddress";
    DataTable dt = null;
    try
    {
        dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Utility.ConnString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                return dt;
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        if(dt != null)
            dt.Dispose();
        throw;
    }
}
```

The idea is that if an exception occurs then there is no way to dispose of the `DataTable` because it will not be passed back to the caller.  So, this is the pattern that will make code analysis happy.

Comment: Your code disposes of the data table even when an exception doesn't occur!

Comment: why not use a using  statement for DataTable as well?

Comment: should be try catch, not try finally

Comment: @Sean Yeah, I've fixed that now.

Comment: @Selman22: because you want to dispose it only in case of an exception, not always.

Answer (score 3):

Fire the tool. DataTables do not need to be disposed. They are IDisposable because they inherit IComponent, but their Dispose() method does nothing. I find it disgusting that MS's own tool does not know this.

Answer (score 0):

The Code Analysis is warning you that this object may not get disposed. As @juharr rightly suggests, you should neutralise the code path where an exception occurs, otherwise the object won't get returned and it won't be explicitly disposed of.  This will get rid of the warning.

Comment: It's specifically calling out the execution path when an exception is thrown.

Comment: As far as I recall, it will still complain even with your try-catch, because there is a code path where the object goes out of scope without being disposed (the one where you return it).

Comment: No, it should not complain about the returning of a non-disposed disposable object.

Comment: Thanks. I just tested and you're absolutely right.  The last time I checked it was long ago, no doubt I implemented the pattern incorrectly without realising.

Answer (score -2):

Check the @juharr answer, and also after you use the Datatable and you don't need it any more just do

```
using(dt){}
```

and it will dispose it for you

Comment: The method is returning that `DataTable`, you shouldn't dispose it!

Comment: @Andrew  I made myself clear after he uses the DT, not in the method. This was a friendly reminder because we are on Friday :D

Comment: But you should know when exactly is the last time you use that `DataTable`. I personally have never seen a `using` without the inline object creation.

Comment: I agree that callers of the method should also dispose of the `DataTable` preferably with a `using` statement unless it's being passed up another level, of course.

Comment: I always use using (including this behavior in the OP question) as a reminder that I always have to use using (any other normal life case)